# fopen returns invalid argument in C

Tags: c

I searched the forum, and can't find the answer to this problem. It seems to be common, but none of the mentioned fixes are applicable.

This is my code for opening a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    FILE *input;
    char path[200];

    printf("Enter the full file path and file name in the following format:"
        "\nC:\\Users\\Username\\etc......\\filename.extension\n");
    fgets(path, 200, stdin);
    printf("%s",path);
    input=fopen(path,"r");
    if (input==NULL) {
        perror("The following errors were encountered");
        return(-1);
    }
}
```

`printf(%s,path)` correctly displays the path and name of the file I want to open, but fopen always returns invalid argument. I have also tried using a pointer to path in fopen, but this always crashes the program.

Comment: This is because `path` will contain a trailing newline character...

Comment: BTW: `void main` is bad, use `int main` instead. Also, `return` is not a function, and thus needs n parentheses around its argument.

Comment: On a side note: you're returning a value `-1` when main is declared as void. Don't do that. Declare main as int and return something from all code paths. While it's not a breaking error, it's bad style.

Comment: @jpw `return VALUE` in a function declared to return `void` is IIRC sufficient cause for the compiler to reject the program outright.  (I don't have my copy of the standard on this computer.)

Comment: And even if `main` is correctly declared as returning `int`, you should not return a negative value because those are reserved for the operating system.  In absence of a good reason to do something else, `#include <stdlib.h>` and return `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` (defined therein to 0 and 1 respectively).

Comment: @Zack Depends on the compiler options I guess. gcc -Wall let it through with a warning, although I imagine -Werror had stopped it from compiling.

Comment: @jpw Yes, but just because GCC is compiling something, it does not mean it is standard compliant.  In C, `void` functions may only use `return` without value or no `return` at all.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that about fgets. Guess I'll have to start using fclose now.

Comment: @5gon12eder Fun fact you were probably not aware of: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are *not* required by the C standard to have any particular value.  However, returning the number zero from `main` is required to have the same effect as returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`!

Comment: Thanks about the return as well! Although codeblocks seems to be ignoring the void specification. So far even void main without returns has returned values.

Answer (score 8):

You are getting `path` with `fgets`. `\n` is considered a valid character by `fgets`. You need to remove it manually.

```
fgets(path, 200, stdin);
path[strlen(path) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: This may not be enough; `fgets` might return an `\r\n`-terminated line (it's not supposed to, but some older C libraries do anyway) or the user might accidentally type trailing spaces.

Comment: `path[strlen(path) - 1]`

Comment: @Zack Or it might return `NULL`, to indicate failure.

Comment: Indeed, it might not be enough, as Zach said, but it told me everything I needed to know. Thanks! I might end up using strrchr to get rid of trailing characters.

Comment: For some reason, I have to use NULL rather than '\0' to make this work.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is *probably* that `fgets` does not remove the trailing `'\n'` from the input line before returning it.  `fopen` cheerfully tries to open a file whose name contains `'\n'`, but (assuming, as your code suggests, that you are using Windows) the operating system does not allow file names to contain that character, which is why you are getting an "Invalid argument" message.  On a Unix-type system, where the kernel imposes far fewer constraints on file names, you would have instead gotten "No such file or directory".  This may be why you didn't find any previous answers to this question; I know I've seen variations before.

Try this:

```
...
fgets(path, 200, stdin);
char *p = path + strlen(path) - 1;
while (isspace(*p)) p--;
*(p+1) = '\0';
printf("%s\n", path);
input = fopen(path, "r");
...
```

You will need `#include <ctype.h>` for `isspace`.